# Displaying a text document from base64 in Webkit

Tags: webkit

Here is a base64 URI for a simple text document:

```
data:@file/plain;base64,VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QhIFRoaXMgaXMgb25seSBhIHRlc3QhCg==
```

I would like to display this in the normal fashion a browser may display a text document. In many browsers (such as Firefox) this is readily achievable by setting the source of a hyperlink to the base64 URI. But on Webkit, from my own testing and from others who use Webkit browsers, this does not work. Instead of displaying the text document, nothing happens.

My question is, is this a bug or a feature of Webkit? Alternatively, is there a way to make this work on Webkit that involves extra steps I am unaware of? Images encoded as base64 display correctly on Webkit using the same methodology, so I cannot imagine why text documents would not.

You can test this yourself in your browser (whatever it is) [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GKI9SJX2Z9WY).

Comment: Please tag to the particular language that you are working on, webkit seems to very common to the swift developers